# CSS, How to move <i> downwards or upwards without affecting inline text?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

This is very hard to explain in a title, but I will show you in a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/myv50428/2/

Basically I want to move the envelope icon downwards, but not affect the test.

So it looks like so:
[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsjAt.png)

But for some reason it is ignoring my i tag in the css.

What it seems to be ignoring:

```
.envelope i {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Hope you guys can help me!

**For those wondering why I want this... It's because I need to do this to center text to the icons, for example if I have a really big icon, I will need to center the text to it.**

Comment: So just to clarify, I want to move the mail icon, but not the text you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as your CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.envelope {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

The `vertical-align:top` sets the `<a>` tag to align in the way that you're looking for. You also want to style the `margin-top` on the `.envelope` class, `<i>` tags behave in weird ways sometimes.

Link to updated JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/myv50428/8/

Hope this helps!

Comment: None of these answers really worked well, but your answer was the best mike, I therefore am accepting yours.

Comment: If anyone is intrested, I change the I tags to divs instead, and it seems to all be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`i` ignores margin because it’s an inline element.

You can move element that way:

```
li i.envelope {
   position: relative;
   top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Did does not work because there is no `<i>` inside the `.envelope` tag. If you set it to `i.envelope` it works.

Comment: Posted an answer from my phone and just fixed your code from the question. rioV8 is right.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is **transform: translateY**

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.envelope {
  margin-right: 10px;
  animation: upDown 1s infinite ease;
}

@keyframes upDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css">

<li><i class="fa fa-envelope envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="">Email:</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.envelope i {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Bro, you have a problem with it. From the example you have provided, `<i>` itself containing `class='envelope'`, whereas you are trying to access the child of `.envelope`. That's why is ignoring. 
You need to do this:

```
.envelope {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px; // or whatever value you want to enter
}
```